# How to match occurance of word in list in makefile

Tags: makefile

I wonder how to match exact occurrence of a given word in the given list of words using only standard makefile operations. In the below example for WORD_TO_MATCH = a the result is positive and apparently wrong.

```
INPUT_LIST= aa bb

WORD_TO_MATCH = aa
#WORD_TO_MATCH = a

ifneq ($(findstring $(WORD_TO_MATCH),$(INPUT_LIST)),)
    $(warning List contains "$(WORD_TO_MATCH)")
else
    $(warning List doesnt contain "$(WORD_TO_MATCH)")
endif
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use filter *instead* of *findstring*:

```
...
ifneq ($(filter $(WORD_TO_MATCH),$(INPUT_LIST)),)  
    $(warning List contains "$(WORD_TO_MATCH)")
...
```

Comment: And now a bonus task - `$(filter ...)` the list on a substring (i.e. not exact match of the word, but words containing - wait for it - the stem of a pattern rule, to specify its dependencies. Where I mean something like: `target_dir/%.o: $(filter <pattern%><stem%>, $(LIST_OF_SOURCES_IN_DIFFERENT_DIRS))`, and in the rule have `%^` return the right files... I'm considering of making a question, but this would be a hard one. (BTW, I've heard about `.SECONDEXPANSION`, but it's practically undocumented).