# ifeq issue I try to understand

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

is my first question here and first time I manage GNU Make so I want to explain my problem.perhaps you could help me to find a light at the end of this tunnel.

That thing Im trying to do is to check a word into my path and do something after check path

I've got that code on make:

```
WORD=GNUMAKE; \
    FOUND=1; \
    echo "$$FOUND"; \
    PWD=$(PWD); \
    ifeq ($(findstring $$WORD,$$PWD),) \
        $(warning list contains "$$WORD") \
    endif
```

but when I run $make I get this error, for me so strange and can't find a solution
could you please help me?

```
/bin/sh: syntax error at line 1: `ifeq' unexpected
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thank you

Comment: `ifeq` is not valid Bash / sh syntax. `if [ -z $(findstring ...) ] ; ... fi ` might work, though.

Comment: nice answer..that was a crappy make thing to do anyway. cheers

Answer (score 4):

Gnu make treats lines joined with `\` as a single line. `ifeq` et. al. need to be on their own line, rather like `#ifdef` in C (if that's any help to you).

You seem rather confused over what make does.

Make executes a makefile in three distinct phases:

1. It reads in the Makefile, building a graph in memory, saving macros/expanding macros as necessary.
2. It looks at what you asked it to make, and decides how to walk the graph.
3. It walks the graph, expanding the shell recipes *before* passing the manufactured string to the shell.

You can get make to do your bidding *as it reads the makefile*

```
WORD = GNUMAKE
FOUND = 1
$(warning ${FOUND})
ifneq ($(findstring ${WORD},${CURDIR}),)
    $(warning list contains "${WORD}")
endif
```

Or you can get make to do this just as it is making the command to pass to the shell (i.e., *before* the shell is executed):

```
.PHONY: target
target:
    $(if $(findstring ${WORD},${CURDIR}),$(warning list contains "${WORD}"))echo Shell command here
```

Or indeed get the shell to do it.

Comment: There is a mistake. The first make snippet should have "ifneq (" instead of "ifeq ("

Comment: Thanks for your details bobbogo, now I understand a little bit more that make thing I would put on practice your recommendations. Greetings

Comment: That is what i get from $make

Makefile:22: 
Makefile:22: list contains ""
FOUND=1
ifneq (,)
/bin/sh: syntax error at line 1: `ifneq' unexpected
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: @Boris: Eh what? `bash` is complaining about `ifneq`? `ifneq` should net get any where near the shell. Line 22? You need to post your Makefile somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it seems does not like as well as variables set between () or {} I should use $$ if I want set any variable. but...should I use ksh? my makefile is simplest to perform this task away from the original that is a bigger one. I'd post it on another answer for you to see.
Thank you!!

Comment: Again, Eh??? Are you using GNU make > 3.80 (`make --version`)? To re-iterate, once make has decided to pass your recipe to the shell, it expands any macros _before_ passing the string to the shell. If your recipe looks like `$(warning hello)echo hi` then make expands `$(warning hello)` to _the empty string_ (as a side effect it prints `Makefile:6: hello`), and thus passes just `echo hi` to the shell, which dutifully prints `hi`.

Answer (score 1):

You are messing make commands with shell commands. **ifeq** is apparently belongs to make but got into shell somehow.

This will find occurance of *GNUMAKE* word in current path, i.e. it will be one of parent directories. Put this into Makefile and call make.

```
INPUT := $(shell pwd | tr -s "/" " ")
WORD=GNUMAKE 
ifneq ($(filter $(WORD),$(INPUT)),) 
   $(warning list contains $(WORD))
endif
```

Comment: Use `:=` instead of `=` when setting a variable using `$(shell)`, unless you like forking out a shell every time you reference `$(INPUT)`.

Comment: Sure, this just an example regarding usage of ifeq/ifneq as stated in question

Comment: Thank you Jack and pmod, I'll try your recommendations and let you know what happenned. Thanks

Comment: It's rarely necessary to use `$(shell...)`. Don't do it if you can avoid it. (Here you could do `$(subst /, ,${CURDIR})` instead.)

Comment: Well, actually I wouldn't use it if I wrote it for this task for myself, it was a correction of original solution by Boris in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006453/how-to-match-occurance-of-word-in-list-in-makefile/4958909#4958909. So, please don't blame for that.

Comment: nice nice, that was really incredible!

Answer (score 0):

```
WORD = GNUMAKE
FOUND = 0
$(warning $$FOUND)
ifneq ($(findstring $$WORD,$(PWD)),)
    $(warning list contains $$WORD)
endif
```

that is exactly what I have been set
hope it helps

Comment: thats what i get '/bin/sh: syntax error at line 1: `ifneq' unexpected' despite there was a problem with my varibles that were set into a target..so baaaaad

Comment: what a crazy thing is that GNU MAKE! only for rats and porks hohoho