# Managing simple variables in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Im trying to manage variables on make, but I see there are several types as shell variables with {}, variables set with () and $$ but, now I just try to manage simple text variables with that simple code in my Makefile

```
@WORD=GNUMAKE
    FOUND=1
    PWD=$(PWD)
    $(findstring $$WORD,$$PWD)
    $(shell echo $$FOUND)
    $(shell echo $$PWD)
```

well, Im really surprised that I only get nothing with that, for me I only could use variables noted with $$ because my $make does not recognize () or {} but the other thing is that compiler gives me an error

```
FOUND=1
PWD=/home/ogonzalezr/GNUMAKE/changedir
/home/ogonzalezr/GNUMAKE/changedir
make: execvp: /home/ogonzalezr/GNUMAKE/changedir: Permission denied
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

Now Im wondering, is my make well set on OS? maybe we are talking about some related bug?
Im really lost, and really twisted as well because I dont understand anything that could happen.

Thanks for your answers,

Greetings for all

Comment: well variables are not so hard, if you got any question about; please dont hesitate to check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006453/how-to-match-occurance-of-word-in-list-in-makefile/4969007#4969007

Answer (score 0):

Where to begin? Your use of variables is wrong.

Put this at the top of the makefile:

```
FOUND = 1

all:
  echo $(FOUND)
```

Then run `make`. You should get this working before you try anything more complicated.

Comment: yes, that is the thing, I was setting variables inside this target..that was a mess but know is OK. thanks for your answer!
but, I would like to manage that variables into a for loop..I try